# getHostAddress() and getInetAddress() in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating TCP socket application. In server side,

```
ss = new ServerSocket(10000);
Socket socket = ss.accept();
String remoteIp = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
String RemotePort = ":"+socket.getLocalPort();
```

I am a little bit confused about the last two lines, getInetAddress() used to return the address of socket connect to, namely is the address of host? and then why we need a getHostAddress()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`socket.getInetAddress()` returns an `InetAddress` object that contains the IP address of the remote machine.

`InetAddress.getHostAddress()` returns a `String` object with the textual representation of that address.

So, to end up with a `String` you can print, that's how you do it.

**Edit:** In case you're not familiar, this is called 'method chaining'. It's the same thing as saying:

```
InetAddress addy = socket.getInetAddress();
String remoteIp = addy.getHostAddress();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brian Roachs answer:

You can also take a look into the Java API to find a description for classes, methods and fields:

- [Socket.getInetAddress()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInetAddress%28%29)
- [InetAddress.getHostAddress()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29)